# Implement navigation with the Navigation components

Tags: android, android-studio, android-architecture-navigation

In the new android studio version there is a new big change. I read the documentation about "Implement navigation with the Navigation components" but can somebody explain to me which is the main difference between this method and the classic one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The navigation architecture component is part of [JetPack](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/?gclid=Cj0KCQiAj4biBRC-ARIsAA4WaFg_x1jpIJs12Og0feQZ5TNNgPkEi3e8noz00RrFLDVt-N2BlEsB2PUaAgNSEALw_wcB)  is a new way to navigate your app.

The main different is that *before* you have multiple activities in your application -still you can- to move to different content areas in your app, now with the nav arch component you can have only one activity and the rest of the features of your app is based on fragments, keeping the single activity as a the main container.

In this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2k8x8V77CrU) Ian Lake the creator of navigation architecture explains why we should use this approach.

Also, here is the guide to Navigation Architecture

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/navigation/

Give a look at these resources.

Best regards.

Pedro Varela

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/21970128)

Comment: Thanks @DavidMaze I improved the answer, hope it is better.